# The number inside an object doesn't update in useState hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
const handleContentData = () => {
    setHasMore(false);
    dispatch(contentList(paramsData));
    setParamsData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      offset: prevState.offset + 24,
    }));
    setHasMore(true);
  };
```

I have this code block and I want to add 24 to offset property each time this function invokes

the initial offset is 0, after that 24 is shown but in other calls it just repeats 24 value

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I use this function in a custom infinite scroll HOC, every time user scrolls down I call **handleContentData** function to get data from server but as I said after 24 the amount of offset doesn't change in other requests. the property value in **prevState** is updated but the amount of new state doesn't get update.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the given code: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-babbage-frzr7w?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Write your component as follows

```
// defining the state
const [obj, setObj] = useState({ title: "Hello", offset: 12 });

// Handle update function
const handleE = () => {
  setObj((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    offset: prevState.offset + 24,
  }));
};

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={handleE}>Click</button>

    <div>{obj.title}</div>
    <div>{obj.offset}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: The issue is I use this function in a custom infinite scroll HOC, every time user scrolls down I call **handleContentData** function to get data from server but as I said after 24 the amount of offset doesn't change in other requests. the property value in **prevState** 
 is updated but the amount of state (like **obj** in your code) doesn't get update